# Bootstrap checkbox button bug

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to use the [checkbox buttons feature](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons) of Bootstrap. When I use it, it doesn't seem to work properly. When I click the checkbox does not necessarily tick.

If you run the code below, and randomly click on the 3 buttons, you will find that the checkboxes have a strange behavior. Sometimes the checkboxes don't activate or deactivate.

Test under Firefox Linux (SolusOS) and Windows.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fork-awesome@1.1.7/css/fork-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

                        <div class="form-group form-inline justify-content-between">
                            <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                                <label class="btn btn-light">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="check1" value="1" name="check1">
                                    <i class="fa fa-5x fa-cloud-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                                <label class="btn btn-light">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="check2" value="1" name="check2">
                                    <i class="fa fa-5x fa-cloud-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                              <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                                <label class="btn btn-light">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="check3" value="1" name="check3">
                                    <i class="fa fa-5x fa-cloud-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </label>
                              </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Did you not post this exact same question yesterday? It still is not clear, what the expected behaviour is and what you think is not working, and we can't help fix a problem when we don't know what it is.

Comment: Yes, but it has been closed due to lack of clarity. Reading your comment, I imagine that is still the case.
It is 3 independent checkboxes. The normal functioning would be that I could check or uncheck any checkbox independently.
In the code I give above, if you try to check and uncheck the checkboxes, you'll see that some checkboxes don't work properly. Sometimes the checkbox does not check, other times it does not uncheck.

Comment: If it was closed for lack of clarity the first time, then you should not re-post the exact same question without improving it to make the problem clearer. If you have extra information, you need to add it into the question itself. Also, I don't see any checkboxes when you run the code so you need to explain what we should be seeing and what is not right.

Comment: I have obviously modified the question before putting it again as Stackoverflow suggests.
In my code we can clearly distinguish 3 lines of this type:
`<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="name" value="1" name="name">`

Comment: It's still not clear what you are expecting to happen! "Strange behaviour" is not a clear problem statement, and you haven't outlined what the correct behaviour is, e.g. can only one image be selected at a time, or can more than 1 be selected, etc.  As I said, we can't help fix a problem when we don't know what it is, so you need to be very specific about what you want to happen.

Comment: Obviously this problem is already known to the Bootstrap developers.
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/31463

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML Syntax isn't correct.
First of all, you are using `type="checkbox"`, as you can see in the [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons) it's `type="radio"`.
And second (maybe not that important), you are using the wrapper class `<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">` three times, not like one time in the documentaition.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fork-awesome@1.1.7/css/fork-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

                        <div class="form-group form-inline justify-content-between">
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">

                                <label class="btn btn-light">
                                    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="wallhack" value="1" name="wallhack">
                                    <i class="fa fa-5x fa-cloud-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </label>
                                <label class="btn btn-light">
                                    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="aimbot" value="1" name="aimbot">
                                    <i class="fa fa-5x fa-cloud-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </label>
                                <label class="btn btn-light">
                                    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="other_hack" value="1" name="other_hack">
                                    <i class="fa fa-5x fa-cloud-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </label>
</div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: In the Bootstrap documentation, the first example uses the checkbox element and not radio.
And I want to use 3 independent checkboxes.

Comment: yea true. it really seems that the checkbox option is kinda bugged.
I suggest you to try to use normal buttons or radio's

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug, [similar to this issue with outline buttons](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/28999), where the `:hover` state and `:outline` state are active when your cursor is over the button, regardless of the actual state. This makes the button appear checked when the actual state is unchecked...until you click away from the button.

Here's what I did to resolve this using the [outlined style single toggle in Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/#toggle-buttons):

CSS:

```
.no-hover-primary:hover { 
    background: none; 
    color: #0d6efd;
}
.no-hover-primary {
    box-shadow:none !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="btn-check-outlined" autocomplete="off">
<label class="btn btn-outline-primary no-hover-primary" for="btn-check-outlined">Toggle Me!</label>
```